# Kerberos SSO with Apache and Zammad not working

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, gssapi, mod-auth-kerb, zammad

I want to introduce the ticket system Zammad with SSO, but after days of configuration it's not working. The LDAP source is Active Directory. I installed it on Debian 12 and switched from Nginx to Apache as described in the [SSO tutorial from Zammad.](https://docs.zammad.org/en/latest/appendix/single-sign-on.html)

Since libapache2-mod-auth-kerb isn't available since Debian 11 by default, I installed it this way:
`wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libapache-mod-auth-kerb/libapache2-mod-auth-kerb_5.4-3_amd64.deb`
`dpkg -i libapache2-mod-auth-kerb_5.4-3_amd64.deb`

After I called https://zammadtest.my-domain.de/auth/sso in Chrome the site redirects to the Zammad login page. After I press the SSO button, I get ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

Here is the Apache errorlog. What I don't understand, in one line the log says **granted**, in the next line it says **denied (no authenticated user yet)**.

I am despairing. I hope someone can help me.

Here is the apache errorlog as Google Table, because stackoverflow thaught this post is spam:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XydjmQHgTaSKQcqq1nshMHvWEFjijKjYyatdrYSqVJo/edit?usp=sharing

I expect SSO to work. I tried everything inkl. asking ChatGPT for help. I also tried GSSAPI as described [here.](https://community.zammad.org/t/fyi-deb11-users-with-apache2-sso/8647)

Comment: Do you have a reason for continuing to use mod_auth_kerb (obsolete and unmaintained) instead of mod_auth_gssapi which **is** available in Debian 11 and 12?